# What are points to consider when choosing between seq_along() and 1:length()

Tags: r, list, loops, functional-programming, iteration

Recently, I have come across a code snippet from another R user on Stackoverflow who printed a `list` of `data.frames` using `kableExtra` by the following initial `for` loop `for (i in 1:length(listofdfs))` followed by the corresponding function. Until now, I always used `for (i in seq_along(listofdfs))` to get the job done. A comparison of both methods on some random `data.frames` did not show any differences (see reprex below).

I was wondering whether someone could elaborate on the points to consider when applying either method in practice independent from printing dfs, etc. Unfortunately, the `R` documentation does not seem to give any information on this specific topic.

Here is a small reprex resulting in the same output:

```
library (dplyr)
library (kableExtra)

# Some random data
city <- rep(c(1:3), each = 4) %>% factor ()
gender <- rep(c("m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f"))
age <- c(32, 54, 67, 35, 19, 84, 34, 46, 67, 41, 20, 75)
working_yrs <- c(16, 27, 39, 16, 2, 50, 16, 23, 48, 21, 0, 57)

# Generating list of dfs by group split
listcity <- data.frame(city, gender, age, working_yrs) %>% group_split (city, keep=TRUE)

# for loop using seq_along
for (i in seq_along(listcity)) {
  print(
    kable(listcity[[i]], caption = "Using seq_along") %>%
      kable_styling("striped", bootstrap_options = "hover", full_width = FALSE)
  )}

# for loop using 1:length
for (i in 1:length(listcity)) {
  print(
    kable(listcity[[i]], caption = "Using 1:length") %>%
      kable_styling("striped", bootstrap_options = "hover", full_width = FALSE)
  )}
```

Comment: The main difference that I am aware of is that `seq_along()` handles empty vectors better. `1:length(listcity)` doesn't work as intended if `length(listcity)` is zero. In that case you are iterating over the nonempty vector `c(1,0)`. This edge case can occur if what you have is the result of filtering, so it isn't rare enough that it can be neglected. I have been bitten by that bug at least once.

Comment: @ john Coleman is correct. There is a good explanation in Hadley Wickham's book R for Data Science  [iteration item 21.2 § 2](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html)

Comment: @ John Coleman @ Peter Thanks to both of you for this helpful Information!